# Differentiating the inner product of two vector fields in terms of covariant derivatives

Tags: differential-geometry

> I'm trying to prove LEMMA 3 below, and I have no idea how $(\quad)_T$ arises when we carry out the inner product, as is indicated by the question mark. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Are $v(t)$ and $w(t)$ tangent to $S$ ? The product of the normal components with $w$ or $v$ will vanish if this is the case.

Comment: A vector field along a curve $\alpha(t)$ on the surface $S$ is a mapping that assigns to each $t$ a tangent vector to $S$ at $\alpha(t)$.

Comment: So $\langle (dv/dt)_N,w \rangle = 0$ since by definition they are orthogonal. Likewise for $dw/dt$.

Comment: Is this Barrett O'neill's book ?

Comment: This comes from the book written by do Carmo.